# How can I make my html td elements fit to changing window sizes?

Tags: html, css

```
**THIS IS MY HTML**

<div class="table">
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">About us</a></td>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">Testimonials</a></td>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">Contact us</a></td>
<tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**THIS IS MY CSS**

```
html,body{
margin:0;
height:100%;
background: linear-gradient(red,pink);
}
.table{
background-color:black;
margin:0;
}
td,a{
padding:25px;
margin:80px;
}
```

When I make the window size smaller, some of the text in td goes to the next line. How to I make that stop?
This is normal:
[image]

This is after I reduce window size:
[image]

Comment: Reason #4976 why one should never use tables for layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following code to your CSS:
`td a { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. It is working. But I want the table and size to reduce along with the window size. How do I do that?

Comment: Lose the `margin:80px` in your `td` and `a` elements; this is the reason the content doesn't get enough space and the lines break easily in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{ margin:0; height:100%; background: linear-gradient(red,pink); } .table{ background-color:black; margin:0; } td,a{ padding:20px;  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">About us</a></td>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">Testimonials</a></td>
<td><a href="otherpage.html">Contact us</a></td>
<tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add to ur body width:100% or watever then in ur table specify width and height in percentages
so let say your table need to match the body width and height then you need to add width:100% and height:100% in your css table or whatever percentages you like

Comment: if you specify table width and height by % then it will decrease size along your windows if that does not work then specidy font size as percentages also

Comment: ok here you are doing wrong padding:25px;
margin:80px; so u specified ur padding and margin by fixed pixel try with percentages aswell see if it works